# FB Login Strict mode is not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am trying make a registration with FB option for my PHP based website. My callback url for the website is

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/fblogincb/
```

I have added that in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs in my Apps Facebook Login settings. The login button of my website correctly invoke the callback url, but when I try to use the access token in my call back page using the follwing code:

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

it return the exception:

> Graph returned an error: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

The redirected URL from FB is:

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/fblogincb/?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

However, turning off the Strict URLs mode does not have this issue. What am I doing wrong here for the Strict URLs mode. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try and pass the exact URL as parameter to the getAccessToken method, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Wow.. it solves the problem? Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I added an answer, including a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and pass the exact redirect URL that was used in the login dialog call, as parameter to the getAccessToken method:

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('http://subdomain.mydomain.com/user/fblogincb/');
```

---

The *exact same* `redirect_uri` parameter value must be passed in both calling the login dialog, and in the subsequent API call that exchanges the code for a token. The SDK has its own "URL detection handler" on board (or you can supply your own, in environments where custom routing logic might require that) for the purpose of determining the current URL - which usually does the job fine, but depending on the exact setup, it can fail sometimes.

I am a bit surprised by the error message, I remember seeing a different one in such cases that explicitly mentioned the redirect_uri mismatch ... but maybe while implementing strict mode something changed internally, dunno.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to update Facebook PHP SDK to latest v5.6.2, strips `code` param from Facebook `redirect_uri` callback

[Facebook SDK for PHP - changelog](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.x/CHANGELOG.md#5x)

- 5.6.2 (2018-02-15)

  - Strip 'code' param (#913)